# How to navigate to new View for Settings for SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Working on a App to show the status of devices, grouped by tags using SwiftUI.  I've got the main view working well showing a list of tags and the status of the devices associated.  I can click on the tag and open a new view to show info about the tag and some info about the devices.

I've looked at [Programatically navigate to new view in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56754117/programatically-navigate-to-new-view-in-swiftui)
 and get the error "Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type"

```
class MenuChoice: BindableObject {
  let didChange = PassthroughSubject<MenuChoice, Never>()
  let willChange = PassthroughSubject<MenuChoice, Never>()
  func login() {
    self.isSettingsViewActive = true
  }
  var isSettingsViewActive = false {
    didSet {
      didChange.send(self)
    }
  }
}

struct ViewMain: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var menuChoice: MenuChoice
  var body: some View  {
    if !menuChoice.isSettingsViewActive {
      ViewSettings()
    } else {
      ViewMain2()
    }
  }
}
```

I want the option (buttons) to navigate to:
** a high level Settings view where I can config overall settings
** a view that is exclusive to info about Devices
** a view that is exclusive to info about Tags

The views work, but I can't find a way to navigate to the view and then return from the view.

Perhaps SwiftUI is not quite ready??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your if statement inside a container, for example: `Group`

```swift
struct ViewMain: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var menuChoice: MenuChoice
  var body: some View  {
      Group {
         if !menuChoice.isSettingsViewActive {
           ViewSettings()
         } else {
           ViewMain2()
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That did resolve the issue with the error for Function declares an opaque return type.  But overall functionality it not yet what I need to move between views.  Time for some household duties, then back to this problem.  Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. If you continue to experiment problems, post a question with more details and we'll try to help. Cheers ;-)