# SwiftUI how can I make my app pause until I receive some API Data?

Tags: swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm : ViewModel
    @State private var username = ""
    private var searchAllowed : Bool{
        if(username.count>2)
        {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Text("Enter your Username:")
                    .font(.title.bold())
                
                
                TextField("Username", text: $username)
                    .frame(width: 280)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                
                
                NavigationLink{
                    ProfileView(vm: vm)
                } label:
                {
                    ZStack{
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .fill(.gray)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                        
                        Text("Search")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .task {
                                await vm.fetchPlayerData()
                            }
                        
                    }
                }
                .disabled(searchAllowed)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

So I want it so that when I press the search `NavigationLink` it'll only take me to the view if the api call was sucessful and I got some particular piece of data I needed.

How can I make it conditional like this? It's all sync so it seems like I can't really wait to see if I have the right data before moving the user into the new `View`.

Comment: Disabling the app is bad practice. For the users, they'll keep pressing the link and wonder why is it not working. Instead, present the view with a `ProgressView` & fetch the data there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically navigate to new view in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56754117/programmatically-navigate-to-new-view-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @NoeOnJupiter said:

In your `NavigationLink` destination, use conditional view logic, that shows `ProgressView`. After your `loadData()` finishes, flip a boolean and show your desired `View` showing API Data.

Comment: Could you maybe try to show me what exactly you mean? What I want is a ProgessView until I have my API Data but I don't really understand how I can do that within NavigationLink? I mean if I put a ProgressView in there at some point won't it just stay a ProgessView once the user clicks it because that's the destination?

Comment: Nvm just found out if I change the view in the navigationLink it automatically changes and doesn't just stay at the one I clicked first